# Let $A$ be a positive semidefinite matrix. If $a_{ii}=0$ for some $i \in \{1, \cdots ,n\}$ then $a_{ij}=0$ $\forall \in \{1,\cdots, n\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to use  [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) but I didn't see a clear way to do it.

I appreciate if you could give me some hints.

Comment: From the Wikipedia link: "An analogous theorem holds for characterizing positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrices, except that it is no longer sufficient to consider only the leading principal minors: a Hermitian matrix M is positive-semidefinite if and only if all principal minors of M are nonnegative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix has a positive semidefinite square root $Q$, $Q^2=A$. The element $a_{ii}$ is the inner product of the $i$-th row of $Q$ with its $i$-column, but since $a_{ii}=0$, and these  two vectors are equal, this means that they are both zero. Now $a_{ij}=\sum_k q_{ik} q_{kj}$, so $a_{ij}=0$ for all $j$. By symmetry, $a_{ji}=a_{ij}=0$.